# is it secure to set oauth token as cookie?

Tags: python, angularjs, django, session, cookies

I have an angular controller that runs in a django app.  I login with django but then my angular app can't authenticate to be able to invoke a service written in django rest framework.

My thinking is that I authenticate with oauth in django and then write the token generated to a cookie.  I can then grab the cookie in angular and use it to make my web service calls.

Is this a secure good idea?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  Third party [browser extensions can sometimes request access to a user's cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies).  If the user grants access to those cookies, then the third party will have access to your user's auth tokens.